Nginx Continuously Failing With Result 'Signal'
I'm doing some work and we have a machine setup on DigitalOcean 5.15.0-100-generic #110-Ubuntu, and it's serving multiple NextJS frontends and a NodeJS backend thruogh PM2 on different localhost ports, which get served on different subdomains of the primary domain. All this is configured using nginx nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu). For SSL, we're using certbot certbot 1.21.0 on the main domain as well as all the subdomains.
We were able to configure everything alright, but every few days I can see that nginx fails and I have to manually do systemctl restart nginx for it to get back up.
This is the nginx status I see when it crashes:
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2024-04-21 08:05:01 UTC; 6h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 1080798 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
        CPU: 22.910s

I couldn't see anything in the nginx error log at that given timestamp.
When checking /var/log/syslog for the timestamp, I found the following:
Apr 21 07:45:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] CRON[1218696]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 21 07:55:02 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] CRON[1219317]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] CRON[1219922]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] CRON[1219923]: (root) CMD (/tmp/.X291-unix/.rsync/b/sync>/dev/null 2>&1)
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: session-3017.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: session-3017.scope: Consumed 1w 4d 9h 37min 52.082s CPU time.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 1082832 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 1082835 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 1082832 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 1082835 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit process 1082832 (nginx) remains running after unit stopped.
Apr 21 08:05:01 [REDACTED FOR PRIVACY] systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit process 1082835 (nginx) remains running after unit stopped.

I read other people were having a similar issue, but instead of having the fail result signal they had a core dump instead so I'm a bit confused. Maybe it's related to certbot? Is there any way to fix this so that I don't have to keep restarting it manually after seeing that the website is down?

This may be a potential solution. I saw a somewhat related article which suggests configuring systemd to auto restart nginx once it detects a failure. This would more so be a temporary solution but if it works then I don't see why not.
This was the proposed fix:
Create directory /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/
Create file /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf with the following contents:
[Unit]
StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5
    
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

Run systemctl daemon-reload
Restart nginx: systemctl restart nginx.service
Maybe this works.
